# What is the best way to add and check authorization token?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am implementing an android application which will validate user details against the server and stores the return token. For subsequent requests it should send the token along with each request. Here are some of the points I need to consider.

1. I am using Retrofit 2 library to send http requests to the server
2. The token will be generated by JWT library and sent back to the client
3. If the token is not present or invalid or expired, the server will throw 400/401 error

**Design**

1. The landing page of android app is not login protected so that user can see the app before using his credentials
2. Once he is on MainActivity, any requests to other screens require authentication. So all other activities will check for token and redirect to login activity.
3. In case any response received from server has 400/401 header, it should also redirect to login page.

Considering the above requirements, I tried to add an interceptor in Retrofit service generator class which which will be executed on every request/response.

**Problem**

The interceptor is executed for every request not just once per activity. i.e. it is opening n number of logic activities if there are n number of async calls in the main activity (because no token will be present for all those requests).

Can someone help me in identify:

1. If there is a better design that can avoid such problem or
2. Is there any way to suspend main activity until login is completed and then resume it.

Comment: When starting the login activity, you could set the intent flag to remove all the other activities (e.g. MainActivity and extra Login's). I think the combination of these two `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` should do the trick. Just an idea though.

Comment: Wouldn't that still an overhead in case there are say 5 call which opens 5 login screens and close 4 before last one settled down? Is there any way to avoid such incident at all?

Comment: You're right, probably is. The other idea may be that the first time you get a `401 header`, cancel all the other async tasks, and then redirect to Login. This seems much smarter anyway :)

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I will explore and see. Thanks anyway for the valuable suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, well it's as simple as `myAsyncTaskInstance.cancel()`. Just put the code in the right places, keep a list of all active tasks, something like that. You can surely figure it out :)